# Horizontal Scroll Bar Always Appearing in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll

I am facing an issue. In my view I have a DataGrid whose Horizontal Scroll Bar's Visibility is set to Auto. Problem I am facing is that the scroll bar is appearing all the time even if there is enough space for DataGrid to expand and completely display itself. I have tried almost everything but couldn't figure out whats is wrong.

I have uploaded a sample application to demonstrate the problem [here](http://uploadingit.com/file/srvkpsxczjyvpqta/Data%20Grid%20Issue.rar). Hoping anyone will point out mistake I am making.

Comment: I have the same problem. anyone know a solution?

Comment: See my answer, it might help you. Worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did following changes/workarounds to solve the issue. It might not be the perfect solution but works for me.

I added two more columns in the `Grid`, one in the start and one at the end.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=m_DataGrid, Path=RowHeaderWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col3, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col4, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="specialCol" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Then I increased the `ColumnSpan` of `DataGrid`

`...Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" ....`

Then I added this line in `Constrcutor` of `Window`

`specialCol.Width = new GridLength (2);`

and changed `UpdateGrid` method to this

```
 void UpdateGrid()
 {
     ScrollViewer scrollview = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(m_DataGrid);
     Visibility verticalVisibility = scrollview.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;

     if (verticalVisibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
     {
       specialCol.Width = new GridLength(20);
       m_Border.Width = m_DataGrid.ActualWidth - m_DataGrid.RowHeaderWidth - 17;
     }
     else
     {
        specialCol.Width = new GridLength(2);
        m_Border.Width = m_DataGrid.ActualWidth - m_DataGrid.RowHeaderWidth;
     }
}
```

I don't see any `HorizontalScrollBar` now until it is required

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the MinWidth you set for all the data grid columns, you could also set the data grid columns Width="*" to fill-in all the space available the them. see the code below

Ok, I found it, please remove the HorizontalAlignment from both m_MainGrid and m_DataGrid, moreover, remove all the ColumnDefinitions in m_MainGrid. I tried it on your solution and it worked.

[image: Please follow the following steps]

```
<Window x:Class="Data_Grid_Issue.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="50" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="m_Border" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="20,0,0,0"
                BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="LightBlue"
                Width="{Binding ElementName=m_DataGrid, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Label Content="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
        <Grid x:Name="m_MainGrid" Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col1, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col2, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col3, Path=ActualWidth}" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=col4, Path=ActualWidth}" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->


            <DataGrid ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="m_DataGrid_ScrollChanged" Width="Auto" x:Name="m_DataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Testing}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,0,0,0" EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      RowHeaderWidth="20"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=a}" MinWidth="200"
                                        x:Name="col1" Header="Col1"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=b}"  MinWidth="200"
                                        x:Name="col2" Header="Col2"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=c}"  MinWidth="200"
                                        x:Name="col3" Header="Col3"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Binding="{Binding Path=d}"  MinWidth="200"
                                        x:Name="col4" Header="Col4"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it out yourself? still not working after doing your suggested changes.. And I want to have a minimum width for my columns..

Comment: First of Thanks for your effort. I think you are not fully understanding the issue here. I have defined all the columns and have done all the alignments to make sure that user see DataGrid in a particular format which you must have observed in the sample application. In my solution I don't want user to see an extra blank column at the end. I want user to fully re-arrange the column order and sizes. I want a header over the grid. I have created whole XAML to make sure all these scenarios work and all these scenarios are working fine in my sample application.

Comment: However the only problem I am facing is that horizontal scroll bar is always appearing. Your solution is just a workaround which solves the the horizontal bar problem but it not achieving the final goal.. I am looking to find out why horizontal bar is appearing in this given context not how to get rid of horizontal bar through any possible way..

Comment: @haris: The normal behavior for the DataGrid is to take all the available horizontal space available in the window and expand along with the window when you re-size it. If you wand to get rid of the extra blank column at the end you can set the width of the last column to Width="*" and the MinWidth="200", the user will still be able to fully re-arrange the columns orders and sizes. I really find the current setup weird and not user friendly.